# To what legislation is Sen. Hagerty referring "that threatens liability for ... companies that do not ... censor ... speech."?

Tags: united-states, senate, legislation, freedom-of-speech

In [Americans, Not Government, Are the Arbiters of Truth](https://www.nationalreview.com/2021/07/americans-not-government-are-the-arbiters-of-truth/), July, 29, 2021, by [Sen. Bill Hagerty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Hagerty) (R-TN) for *National Review*, Hagerty complains that

> When the White House doesn’t like what Americans are saying, they pick up the phone and use government power to pressure unaccountable Big Tech corporations to censor Americans.

To that end, Hagerty and others have introduced the *[Disclose Government Censorship Act](https://www.rubio.senate.gov/public/_cache/files/0af164f9-9ab1-4beb-8445-d200965de417/3A24431D7C6CC315BF303BDA31B6293A.sil21874.pdf)* and other bills (e.g., [PRESERVE Online Speech Act](https://www.rubio.senate.gov/public/_cache/files/18103618-09b2-4f85-b639-862c693a6724/11176E1AAF15279F3A38B2E8E52F7890.rubio-preserve-online-speech-act.pdf)) expanding on their views opposing this alleged censorship.

While the text for the Republican sponsored bills is locatable by name, Hagerty refers to certain legislation by Senate Democrats.

> Incredibly, some Democrats in the Senate have doubled down on the White House’s censorship push by introducing legislation that threatens liability for Big Tech companies that do not — in their view — adequately censor Americans’ speech. This only underscores the need for transparency regarding the degree to which government is directing this speech-suppression operation.

To what legislation is Sen. Hagerty referring "that threatens liability for ... companies that do not ... censor ... speech."?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Senator Hagerty didn't name names, we can only guess, but my guess is that he is referring to the [Health Misinformation Act of 2021](https://www.klobuchar.senate.gov/public/_cache/files/3/5/35599177-e826-4155-bb92-785d9c50c452/61E493711AE47642A9416719C042404F.health-misinformation-act.pdf) introduced a week earlier (22 July 2021) by Democratic Senators Amy Klobuchar and Ben Ray Luján. The proposed bill asks for an exclusion to the protections offered to websites by Section 230 of the Communications Act of 1934 in the special case of medical misinformation posted on websites during a federally-declared medical emergency.